# C# Grouping a sorted List by following value

Tags: c#, group-by, sortedlist

I have a sorted "List orders".
The list is already ordered and looks like this:

```
class Order {
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string DeliveryPerson { get; set; }
}
```

They are already sorted by Id:

```
Order12 [DeliveryPerson: Andrea]
Order13 [DeliveryPerson: David]
Order14 [DeliveryPerson: Andrea]
Order15 [DeliveryPerson: Andrea]
Order16 [DeliveryPerson: Linda]
...
```

Now I want to group them by DeliveryPerson BUT depending on the following Id:
--> so Order12 is one group,
Order 13 is one group
but Order 14 and 15 are in one group together because from perspective of Order14, Order 15 has the same DeliveryPerson.
(Order16 is a new group again)

How do I do that? Do I still have to work with lists or IEnumerables or ...?
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: The Code part in "Class Order" is just one part of the Class.
In this example they get the delivery person depending on where they have to drive to.
Imagine they drive 10 minutes per order, but it takes 5-6 minutes to cook the order.
When the next Order is in the same region(--> ergo same driver because one driver is responisble for a specific region) he can wait for the next order and can than deliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want kind of consecutive grouping? You can use the following loop:

```
List<Order> orders = // your list

List<List<Order>> orderGroups = new List<List<Order>>();
if(orders.Count > 0) orderGroups.Add(new List<Order> { orders[0] });

for (int i = 1; i < orders.Count; i++)
{
    Order currentOrder = orders[i];
    if (orders[i - 1].DeliveryPerson != currentOrder.DeliveryPerson)
        orderGroups.Add(new List<Order> { currentOrder });
    else
        orderGroups.Last().Add(currentOrder);
}
```

Comment: That's perfect and to be honest very clever to start the for-loop with one and look back
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this extension might be helpful for you, be my guest ;)

```
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupByFollowingValue<TKey, TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> elements, Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> o = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count();)
        {
            int s = i;
            var ts = elements.Skip(s).TakeWhile(x => keySelector.Invoke(x).Equals(elements.Select(keySelector).ElementAt(s)));
            i += ts.Count();
            if (o != null) o = o.Concat(ts.GroupBy(keySelector));
            else o = ts.GroupBy(keySelector);
        }
#if DEBUG
        foreach (var t in o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\r\n{t.Key}");
            foreach (var i in t) { Console.Write($"\t{i}"); }
        } 
#endif
        return o;
    }
```